# Angular2: Component host property

Tags: angular

What does `@Component.host` property stand for?

According to [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html) it stands for:

> host - map of class property to host element bindings for events, properties and attributes.

I don't quite figure out what's it for?

I'm posing this in order to understand a stuff code I've stuck last days.

The code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'layout',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './layout.template.html',
  host: {
    '[class.nav-static]' : 'config.state["nav-static"]',
    '[class.chat-sidebar-opened]' : 'chatOpened',
    '[class.app]' : 'true',
    id: 'app'
  }
})
export class Layout {
```

Answer (score 44):

I have added class to host tag.

Like following:

- Component

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'mytag',
    templateUrl: './layout.template.html',
    host: {
      'class' : 'myclass1 myclass2 myclass3'
    }
  })
  export class MyTagComponent {
  ```
- View code

  `<mytag></mytag>`
- Result

  `<mytag class="myclass1 myclass2 myclass3"></mytag>`

Answer (score 7):

based on [this](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.angular2/Directive/host.html) document, the directive properties inside your host property (`[class.nav-static]`, `[class.chat-sidebar-opened]` and `[class.app]` in your code snippet) should get changed whenever their corresponding expression values get changed.

For example, your `[class.nav-static]` property will get the value of `'config.state["nav-static"]'` expression and it will get updated whenever the expression's value gets updated.

Answer (score 7):

The host property is used to bind the events to all the attributes to that particular class component.See my code this would help you as I want focus to my component and focus out when no use

```
host: {
    '(window:blur)': 'focusOutFunction($event)',
    '(window:focus)': 'focusInFunction($event)',
  }
```

this `focusOutFunction` is active when window is blur which I binded with `(window:blur)`event and `focusInFunction` whic I binded with `(window:focus)`  event.
It works on my whole attributes declared within this class component.Hope this would help you to understand

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent of @HostListener and @HostBinding.

In angular style reference, they said:

> Consider preferring the @HostListener and @HostBinding to the host
> property of the @Directive and @Component decorators

Answer (score 1):

With host property, we can only attach classes or events with component as examples are given in other answers. So, if I try something like:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-selecter',
  host: {
    fxLayout:'row',
    fxLayoutAlign:'start stretch', 
    fxLayoutGap:'10px'  
  },
  providers: [
    my-provider
  ],
  templateUrl: './my-template.component.html'
})
```

It won't apply Flex-layout attributes on my component, as per my intention.